# Defining width:100% in css file, not working in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have the following css code:

```
td.tdhover input:hover,td.tdhover select:hover,td.tdhover textarea:hover{
 background: #f2f5a9;
 color:#ff0000;
}
td.tdhover select, td.tdhover input, td.tdhover textarea{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
}
td.tdhover input.nobor,td.tdhover textarea.nobor{
 border:none;
}
```

and then, I have this html:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;">Poll Name </td>
    <td style="width:5px;"><input type="text" class="nobor"></td>
    <td class="tdhover"><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It is not working in chrome but works perfectly fine in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>[A quick look at the Docs: *box-sizing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)</sub>

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aqAMoZip/1/edit)

```
td.tdhover select,
td.tdhover input,
td.tdhover textarea{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box ;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box ;
          box-sizing: border-box ;
   /*position: relative ; (OT) why this? */
   width: 100% ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

width:100%; is relative to its parent. in other the container that the element is in.

You may have to specify a with for the container. Compare the two :

```
<table id="table1" border="1" style="width:100%;">
   ...
</table>

<div style="width:200px;">
   <table id="table2" border="1" style="width:100%;">
      ...
   </table>
</div>
```